# consolidate subversion checkin emails

Tags: svn, email, version-control

I just started hacking on a script to consolidate check-in emails into a ten min window to reduce the amount of svn email people get (and make it more readable). This sounds like the kind of common problem that may have been solved before.

How can I reduce the number of individual checkin notification emails my colligues get?

Comment: Are those mails sent by commit hooks?

Comment: yes, though i can change that if there is a better way

Comment: The only solution I can come up with is a commit hook that stores commit events into a separate database. Another script (cronjob) would then periodically query that DB and send cumulated notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having your commit hook send e-mails, how about running a cron task every ten minutes, hour, or whatever interval, to check for commits in the preceding however-many-minutes and send a notification about them?  How this would work depends somewhat on what information you have in the e-mails, who is supposed to get which e-mails, etc.

An alternative would be to have the commit hook store information about the commit in a database, then have the cron task pick up that information and do the mailing.  However, this may be less clean than the first idea I mentioned.

Comment: Too bad, comments don't contribute to rep. +1 then.

Comment: @Linus Kleen If it makes you feel any better, I didn't see your comment until after I submitted my answer.

Comment: That's quite alright. I don't like giving one-liners as answers. You elaborated more on the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on previous suggestions. I'd run a cron job every hour / 10 mins which svn log command and pipes that to an email list / addresses.

i.e.

svn log --verbose --revision "fromdate:todate" file:///path/to/repo

you'll need to wrap this command up with a perl/bash script to insert the date/time range